# Multiple images of a car over hot road

Tags: optics, refraction

I am wondering about this image of three cars on a hot road, which is from Wikipedia:

[image: Wiki image]

I am seeing two images of the white car in the center of the image. One regular image and one which seems to be reflected from the road. From what I read in [Feynman's lecture](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_26.html) this is due toe the temperature gradient in the air due to the hot road. This leads to a gradient in the refractive index in the air. This allows for curved paths to be paths of stationary time (Fermat's principle). So the additional image comes from the violet path in the sketch below

[image]

And I assume the regular image comes from the green path. All the paths in between the green and the violet (like the blue path) are not stationary and hence do not contribute.  We have exactly **two stationary paths** here (green and violet) and this is why we see the white car twice.

**Question 1:** Is my understanding correct until here?

**Question 2:** Why do I see several copies of the headlights of the truck in the back of the image? Are there more than two stationary paths for the light coming from that truck? And why? What is different compared to the car in the center of the image?

Comment: There is hot air near the road surface and the air cools with height.  This creates air with a refractive index that varies with height and bends the path of the light - it's a type of mirage, see the camel image half way down here https://www.britannica.com/topic/mirage-optical-illusion

Comment: Hi @JohnHunter, thanks for your comment! I know about the gradient in the refractive index, although my question did not mention it. I edited my text to add that information. I highlighted the relevant questions at the end of the text. (Question 1 is mainly about there being **two** stationary paths at the same time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$: No. Your eye has a lens. For each point on the car, there is a cone of direct paths from the point to your eye. The lens focuses light from all of those paths to a point on your retina. A camera works much the same way.

There is also a distorted cone that heads toward the road, is bent by non-uniformly hot air near the road, and winds up headed toward your eye. Again your eye focuses it to a point on the retina. As this cone is on final approach to your eye, it is headed upward from the road. The light you receive is just as if there was a car where the road is. So it looks like a car in that direction.

$2$: It looks like the road is not perfectly flat. There seem to be low spots where puddles would collect on a rainy day. This changes the shape of the layer of hot air near the surface.

It could also be differences in road color or composition creating local hot spots.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! Regarding 1: You are saying "no". What exactly from my explanation is wrong? Also regarding your explanation: Is this focus argument really so relevant? Especially if we assume a pinhole camera model?

Comment: There are more than exactly two paths or rays. There are two cones of paths that converge on points in your retina. On second thought, perhaps that is what you meant. Yes, there are exactly two cones that enter your eye.

Comment: yeah ok. I abstracted away the whole camera and eye thing, the same way Feynman did in his lecture. Then it is not about cones. The statement then is: If we pick one single point on the car "A" and one single point on the camera lens (maybe its center) "B", then there are exactly two paths from A to B that are actually being "realized" by the light. From your comment I understand that this is true. This answers my question 1, and I think your explanation for question 2 is also convincing. Thanks :)!